# wordpress search by custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, search

i make a wordpress advance search for a movie site but i have a trouble with search submit.
i'm not use of html forms just get values of input elements with jquery.
my search parameters are category_name and some custom fields like (genre, rate) and more...
now i want to submit my search using jquery or send with GET or POST method to index page and with php $_GET submit search ...
please help me! i'm not want to rewrite my post loop like this tutorial:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

just want filter my posts.
i'm get all user entered filter in jquery:

```
    $("#tw-search-button").click(function () {
    var url = $("#tw-search-box").attr("data-search-url");
    var tw_sort = $("#tw-search-sort").attr("data-value");
    var tw_genre = $("#tw-search-genre").attr("data-value");
    var tw_quality = $("#tw-search-quality").attr("data-value");
    var tw_country = $("#tw-search-country").attr("data-value");
    var tw_age = $("#tw-search-age").attr("data-value");
    var tw_lang = $("#tw-search-lang").attr("data-value");
    var tw_date = dateRange.noUiSlider.get();
    var tw_rate = rateRange.noUiSlider.get();
    var tw_persian_sound = $("#tw-search-psound").attr("data-checked");
    var tw_persian_sub = $("#tw-search-psub").attr("data-checked");
    var tw_s_persian_sound = $("#tw-search-spsound").attr("data-checked");
    var tw_special_s = $("#tw-search-ss").attr("data-checked");
    tw_sort = (tw_sort === "all") ? "" : tw_sort;
    tw_genre = (tw_genre === "all") ? "" : tw_genre;
    tw_quality = (tw_quality === "all") ? "" : tw_quality;
    tw_country = (tw_country === "all") ? "" : tw_country;
    tw_age = (tw_age === "all") ? "" : tw_age;
    tw_lang = (tw_lang === "all") ? "" : tw_lang;

    //alert(url + "?s=search+term&category_name=" + tw_genre);
    //$(location).attr('href',url + "?category_name=" + tw_genre + "&movie_quality=" + tw_quality + "&movie_country=" + tw_country + "&movie_age=" + tw_age + "&movie_language=" + tw_lang);
    //$(location).attr('href',url + "?category_name=" + tw_genre);
});
```

for example in tw_lang i have language of movie (get from custom fields).
now can i send this variables to url with get like commented codes to submit search?
like:`test.com/?category_name=aaa&movie_age=bbb`
 or i should send this values to a php page and submit?
please help me. thanks...

Comment: you will have to write search yourself. WordPress does not support this kind of search with get parameters.

Comment: how do i that? send tutorial please...

Comment: see wp query https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: should i rewrite my post loop?

Comment: can i use these jquery codes for that? or i should create a html form...